# lda.collapsed.gibbs.sampler model and top words ranking

Tags: r, statistics, lda

I have a model generated by the function *lda.collapsed.gibbs.sampler*, from the lda package, and i need to know the "relevance" of the top words.
When using the

```
    top.topic.words(result$topics, 10, by.score=TRUE)
```

i get a list of top 10 words for each topic, but i'd like to see the percentage of the topic that those 10 words represent. I guess the information exists, because there is a "score", but I'm not really familiar with the statistical methods of the Gibbs sampler.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by percentage of the topic?  Do you mean the probability of any of those words being produced by the topic?  Or perhaps the fraction of Gibbs assignments to those topic-word pairs?

Comment: The second one, I think. I'd like to know how much "weight" the words have in the topic. I'm not really sure about the formal expression for that :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this may be what you want:

```
for (ii in 1:nrow(result$topics)) {
  print(
    head(
      cumsum(
        sort(result$topics[ii,], decreasing=TRUE)
      ),
      n = 20
    ) / result$topic_sums[ii]
  ) 
}
```

Let's break it down.  If you want the fraction of Gibbs assignments, then that is easy. The LDA routine returns the number of assignments to each (word, topic) pair.  So all you have to do is sort each row of the `result$topics` to get the top words (this is essentially what `top.topic.words` does if you set `by.score=FALSE`).  Once you have it in sorted order you can just see, for each topic, how many counts occur for that word versus for the entire topic.  To do that I divide by `result$topic_sums` which contains the total number of assignments of that topic.  Finally, I use `cumsum` so you can see the running total weight for words in that topic.